# Oracle - Startup error with oracle_unqname

Tags: oracle, centos

I can not run `/etc/init.d/dbora`.
When running through the terminal it reports the following problem:

**Shell**

> [root@localhost init.d]# ./dbora start Starting... Processing Database
>   instance "ORA11G": log file
>   /ora01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/startup.log Environment variable
>   ORACLE_UNQNAME not defined. Please set ORACLE_UNQNAME to database
>   unique name.

My User Linux: oracle

**Script**

> ## !/bin/bash
>
> ```
> # versao: 1.0  
> export TMP=/tmp
> export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=centos7.dbaora.com
> export ORACLE_UNQNAME=oracle
> export ORACLE_BASE=/ora01/app/oracle
> export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/db_1
> export ORACLE_SID=ORA11G
> export ORACLE_OWNER=oracle
>
> PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
>
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib;
> export CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib;
>
> alias cdob='cd $ORACLE_BASE'
> alias cdoh='cd $ORACLE_HOME'
> alias tns='cd $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin'
> alias envo='env | grep ORACLE'
>
> umask 022 
>
> start(){
>    echo "Starting..."
>    su - $ORACLE_OWNER -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbstart $ORACLE_HOME"
>    su - $ORACLE_OWNER -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/emctl start dbconsole"
>    touch /var/lock/subsys/dbora
> }
>
> stop(){
>    echo "Stopping..."
>    su - $ORACLE_OWNER -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/emctl stop dbconsole"
>    su - $ORACLE_OWNER -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbshut $ORACLE_HOME"
>    rm -f /var/lock/subsys/dbora
> }
>
> restart(){
>    stop
>    start
> }
>
> usage(){
>    echo "usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
> }
>
> if [ `id -u` -ne 0 ]
> then
>    echo "Este script deve ser executado como root"
>    exit
> fi
>
> case $1 in
>    'start') start;;
>    'stop') stop;;
>    'restart') restart;;
>    *) usage;;
> esac
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORACLE_UNQNAME` is an OS environmental variable used by Oracle Enterprise Manager; it supports managing multiple databases from one OEM instance.

It looks like you haven't set a value yourself, probably because you only have the one database so it's already unique, right :) Nevertheless you need to give it a different value from `oracle`: `orcl` is traditional and will do the trick. In Linux you can set it from the command line using `export` like any other environment variable, or just change the value in your script.

Comment: After the command line 'export ORACLE OWNER = oracle' I added the line 'export ORACLE_UNQNAME' and even then the Script does not recognize. Could you correct me?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. You need to change the default value `oracle` to **something different**.